# Find zeros for solutions to differential equations in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations

Given the following code:

```
s := NDSolve[{x''[t] == -x[t], x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 5 }]
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 3}]
```

This plots the solution to the differential equation. How would I numerically solve for a zero of x[t] where t ranges between 0 and 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original question was answered by @rcollyer. I am answering the question you posted in your first comment to rcollyer's answer:

> But what if instead our s is "s := NDSolve[{x'[t]^2 == -x[t]^3 - x[t] + 1, x[0] == 0.5}, x, {t, 0, 5}]" Then the FindRoot function just gives back an error while the plot shows that there is a zero around 0.6 or so.

So:

```
s = NDSolve[{x'[t]^2 == -x[t]^3 - x[t] + 1, x[0] == 0.5}, 
             x, {t, 0, 1}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 1}]
FindRoot[x[t] /. s[[1]], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
{t -> 0.60527}
```

**Edit**

Answering rcollyer's comment, the "second line" comes from the squared derivative, as in:

```
s = NDSolve[{x'[t]^2 == Sin[t], x[0] == 0.5}, x[t], {t, 0, Pi}];
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t]} /. s], {t, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

Coming from:

```
DSolve[{x'[t]^2 == Sin[t]}, x[t], t]
(*
{{x[t] -> C[1] - 2 EllipticE[1/2 (Pi/2 - t), 2]}, 
 {x[t] -> C[1] + 2 EllipticE[1/2 (Pi/2 - t), 2]}}
*)
```

Comment: where does the second line come from?

Answer (score 2):

[`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindRoot.html) works

```
In[1]:=  FindRoot[x[t] /. s, {t, 0, 3}]
Out[1]:= {t -> 2.35619}
```

Comment: But what if instead our s is "s := NDSolve[{x'[t]^2 == -x[t]^3 - x[t] + 1, x[0] == 0.5}, x, {t, 0, 5}]" Then the FindRoot function just gives back an error while the plot shows that there is a zero around 0.6 or so.

Comment: @LiKun, I didn't mention it, but there is no purpose for using `:=` (`SetDelayed`) here. It re-executes `NDSolve` every time `s` is accessed, but for your system that isn't necessary. Use `=` (`Set`) instead, then `s` will only be executed once.

Comment: @LiKun What is the error?  it looks like there's a singularity that could be causing the error

Comment: @FooBah, there can't be a singularity, its a 2nd order linear differential equation with general solution `a Sin[t] + b Cos[t]`.

Comment: @rcollyer I was referring to your second part: x'[t]^2 == -x[t]^3 - x[t] + 1

Comment: @FooBah, I completely missed the change. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @rcollyer haha you should have said the solution was `Cos[t]+Sin[t]` -- look at the initial conditions :P

Comment: @LiKun, that is very different then your original equation, and much harder to integrate. `NDSolve` should be generating errors, itself. Adding `Method->"StiffnessSwitching"` to `NDSolve` will resolve the second error, but the first error cannot be as easily recovered from. But, as you know the root is near 0.6 from the plot, you can limit the range over which `FindRoot` searches. I used `{t,0,3}` and got `t->0.605323`.

Comment: @FooBah, hence the phrase "general solution." I didn't want to bother with actually determining the coefficients.